# how to separate the map keys when i'm using in the jsp side by using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
Map<String, List<OfferBean>> map = new HashMap<String, List<OfferBean>>();
List<OfferBean> al=new ArrayList<OfferBean>();
List<OfferBean> bl=new ArrayList<OfferBean>();
OfferBean of=null;
sql="select * from catgory";// here i'm using one table data
ps1=c.prepareStatement(sql);
ps1.execute();
rs=ps1.getResultSet();
while(rs.next())
{
    of=new OfferBean();
    of.setCategory(rs.getString("catgoryname"));
    al.add(of);
}
sql="select * from projectname where sl_no_projectname";//here on more table data
ps1=c.prepareStatement(sql);
ps1.execute();
rs=ps1.getResultSet();
while(rs.next())
{
    of=new OfferBean();
    of.setCategory(rs.getString("categoryname"));
    bl.add(of);
}
map.put("key", al); // here i'm put two table data  in the map using keys 
map.put("key1",bl);
return map;
```

How to separate the two keys when I'm retrieving at the jsp side by using jstl the jstl code is like this:

```
<c:forEach var="sample" items="${sampleMap}">
  Key : ${sample.key}
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${sample.value}">
 <option>${item.category}</option>  
  </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
```

I want to place the two table data in two different places.

Comment: Your question is not very clear at least to me. What do you mean by separate two keys?

Comment: actually i'm using two arraylist over there and those two array list i'm placing inside  map i want to access those two array list using jstl for loop one after the other thank u

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? It looks fine.

Comment: i do want to split two tables data using jstl for loop

Comment: Which two tables are you talking about? It would be better if you edit your question to explain what exactly did you expected, and what you got. Currently your question is too vague to be answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better option is replace map to two separate lists.

in server side

```
 request.setAttribute("al", al);   
 request.setAttribute("bl", bl);  
or
 request.setAttribute("al",map.get("key"));   
 request.setAttribute("bl",map.get("key1"));
```

in the jsp

```
<c:forEach var="a" items="${al}">
     <option>${a.category}</option>  
</c:forEach>


<c:forEach var="b" items="${bl}">
     <option>${b.category}</option>  
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: if i replace map how it possible to return two list values from javaclass

Comment: instead of request.setAttribute("sampleMap", map); use this  request.setAttribute("al",map.get("key"));   
 request.setAttribute("bl",map.get("key1"));

Comment: He is setting the `attribute` in the request. Just use `request.getAttribute("a1")`.